# How to filter reaction times differently for each subject in R

Tags: r, list, time, numeric

I want to filter reaction times (RTs), discarding RTs greater than 3 SDs from the mean for each subject. I used the function aggregate to have mean and sd for each participant

```
aggregate(DB$rt, list(DB$subject), FUN=mean)
aggregate(DB$rt, list(DB$subject), FUN=sd)
```

but, since it is a list, when I try to filter

```
DB_r <- DB %>%
  filter(rt < aggregate(DB$rt, list(DB$subject), FUN=mean)+3*aggregate(DB$rt, list(DB$subject), FUN=sd))
```

I get this error

> Error in `filter()`:
> ! Problem while computing `..1 = rt < ...`.
> Caused by error in `FUN()`:
> ! non-numeric argument to binary operator

Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion :)

I tried to fix it with data.matrix (to turn the list into a numeric form) but it did not work, it said "dims [product 66] do not match the length of object [474928]"

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, CG96. To enable others to help with your question, please provide the minimal necessary example data (see `?dput`) and an example of how your expected result should look like: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the logic directly in `dplyr::filter()` without needing any additional processing with `aggregate`. If you have these data:

```
set.seed(123)
DB <- data.frame(subject = 1:4,
                 rt = rnbinom(100, mu = 2, size = 1))
```

You can easily combine everything into a single `filter` statement:

```
dplyr::filter(DB, rt < mean(rt) + sd(rt) * 3, 
              .by = subject)

#   subject rt
#1        1  1
#2        2  4
#3        3  3
#4        4  6
#5        1  3
#6        2  1
#7        3  4
#8        1  0
#9        2  0
#10       3  2
# ...
```

You can see what its doing if we mutate to show the `cutoff` values and if we should `keep` those values:

```
dplyr::mutate(DB, cutoff = mean(rt) + sd(rt) * 3,
         keep = rt < mean(rt) + sd(rt) * 3, 
         .by = subject)

#  subject rt    cutoff  keep
#1        1  1  8.252067  TRUE
#2        2  4 12.017286  TRUE
#3        3  3  8.080741  TRUE
#4        4  6  8.951358  TRUE
#5        1  3  8.252067  TRUE
#6        2  1 12.017286  TRUE
#7        3  4  8.080741  TRUE
#8        4  9  8.951358 FALSE
#9        1  0  8.252067  TRUE
#10       2  0 12.017286  TRUE
# ...
```

Note, previous versions of `dplyr` may need to use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)

DB %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  filter(rt < mean(rt) + sd(rt) * 3)
```

You could also do this in base R by:

```
cutoffs <- aggregate(DB$rt, list(DB$subject), 
                     function(x) mean(x) + sd(x) * 3)

DB[DB$rt < cutoffs$x[match(DB$subject, cutoffs$Group.1)],]

#     subject rt
# 1         1  1
# 2         2  4
# 3         3  3
# 4         4  6
# 5         1  3
# 6         2  1
# 7         3  4
# 9         1  0
# 10        2  0
# 11        3  2
```